# How a continuous map from a compact m-manifold into $\mathbb{R^n}$ is an open map?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

In the proof of Theorem 36.2 Munkres' Topology it claims implicitly that because X is compact thus f is an open map.

> To prove that F is an imbedding we need only to show that F is injective *(because X is compact) *.

I believe by compactness it implies continuity of the inverse map to make it a homeomorphism. But how it is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

- If $F$ is a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, then $F$ is a closed map.
- An injective closed map is an open map onto its image.

The idea for the first part is the same as in the proof of Theorem 26.6 in Munkres.